# What exactly does 'reverse use-dependence' mean?

Tags: pharmacology

I understand 'use-dependence' related to a drug, for instance, more angiotensin2 effects in a hypertensive more prominent is the action of angiotensin2 receptor blockers. But I do not get the term, 'Reverse use-dependence'.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_channel_blocker
In this site, in Medical Uses, the term is mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reverse use dependence** is the reduction of a drug's efficacy with the repeated use of the target. This contrasts with ordinary *use dependence*, for instance with [$\mathrm{Na}^+$ blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_channel_blocker) local anaesthetics, where they exert *more* block after tissue use. Reverse use dependence is particularly (but not exclusively) seen with channel blockers such as [quinidine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinidine).

Quinidine is a $\mathrm{Na}^+/\mathrm{K}^+$ blocker that can [slow heart rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronotropic), and does so more effectively when the heart rate is already slow. Increased use of the tissue, with a raised heart rate, reduces the effectiveness of the drug. So, strangely, quinidine exerts *less* block when the target is in use. This is shown in figure 4 from (Breithardt et al., 1995). As the tissue is used *less* (cardiac cycle length increases), the effect of the drug becomes *stronger* (action potential duration prolongation increases).
[image: Reverse use dependence]

The reverse use dependence of quinidine can be demonstrated on a molecular level with application of quinidine to a [voltage-clamped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_clamp) channel with an [$\mathrm{i}_\mathrm{Ks}$ current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KCNE1). We see better block when short electrical pulses are given than when longer ones are. The mechanism behind use- and reverse use dependence is by *state-dependent affinities*, e.g. the drug can bind more easily to the channel in open/closed state. For example, a channel blocker whose binding site becomes occluded when the channel is opened could exhibit use dependent block.

But be warned: reverse use dependent drugs may also exhibit *normal* use dependence. Quinidine is not just reverse use dependent, but also *use dependent* 
as a $\mathrm{Na}^+$ blocker. The type of tissue and its state change the effect of the drug and must be taken into account.

See (Breithardt et al., 1995) for a review of the topic:

> In 1990 Hondeghem and Snyders introduced the concept of **reverse use dependence** as being a drug effect which is less marked with increased use. Specifically
>   quinidine, N-acetyl-procainamide and sotalol lengthened action potential
>   duration markedly at slow heart rates but much less or not at all at fast heart rates
>   (Fig. 4 [27)). Frequently, reverse use dependence has become equated with reverse 
>   use-dependent block of ion channels. Although reverse use-dependent block of ion
>   channels can lead to a reverse use-dependent drug effect, this does not need to be
>   the case. Worse, reverse use-dependent drug effect does not require reverse use dependent block of channels.

**References:**

- [Breithardt, G., Borggrefe, M., Camm, A., Shenasa, M., Haverkamp, W. and Hindricks, G. (1995). Antiarrhythmic Drugs. pp.97-98.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-85624-2_6)